# Spinner On item selected display/get listview

Tags: android

I would like to display a listview when an item is selected in Spinner. The listview should appear just below the spinner in the same layout based on the item selected.

Ex: When a customer's name is selected in a Spinner, his details should appear in a listview.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

for this defined our layout file as LinearLayout
                                       |
                                       |
                                       |***_****SpinnerView
                                       |
                                       |*_____LinearLayOutFor ListView

and dynamically u take one listView and add that listview ti LinearLayout when spinner item click listener